# Getting the entire JSON request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How can I read a JSON request?

```
$request->all();  //Uncaught ErrorException: Array to string conversion
```

This does not work.

```
$request->('title');
```

This works and gets the title param.

But how can I get the entire data set?

After some googleing I see there was once a method called:

```
$request->json()->all();
```

But this no longer appears to work.

Comment: What does `dd($request->all())` show?

Comment: Uncaught ErrorException: Array to string conversion

Comment: Use it with `dd()`. What does it show?

Comment: "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str>1</span>" and more spans like this with data

Comment: weird, just tried to fire a json load to a laravel endpoint and did a dd(request()->all());  it worked I get the whole json printed.

Comment: $request->all() working in my end too

Comment: @panthro can you please show us some of your implementation??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
dd(request()->all());
```

Since `$request` is an object of `Request` class, there is no property for `$request->all()`

Answer (score -1):

"When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the JSON data via the input method as long as the Content-Type header of the request is properly set to application/json. 
You may even use "dot" syntax to dig into JSON arrays:"

`$name = $request->input('user.name');`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input